# Unable to install yarn through npm

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I am trying to install yarn through npm on Mac by referring the documentation given here: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#mac-stable

```
npm install --global yarn
```

However when I run this command in terminal, I am getting the following error and the package is not being installed

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
```

I also ran this command but nothing happened. I am also seeing messages like - this operation was rejected by your operating system. I haven't used yarn in a year, and everything was working fine, but suddenly I am running into all this. Would love to know what I am doing wrong here and how I can resolve this.

This the error message that comes

```
The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: Is this happening because of some new OS updates?

Answer (score 1):

As warning messages indicate, global `-global` and `-local` appear to be deprecated. However, instead of global, you can use the `-location=global` command.
`-global` and `-local` is deprecated.

- Use This command:

```
npm install --location=global create-react-app
```

- Instead of:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Comment: I want to install yarn and then use that to create react app, don't know why I am unable to use yarn

Comment: Can You Check This Video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TyGCZZaY0yc)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm install --location=global yarn
```

This command worked for me